# Change photo size during orientation change

Tags: android, titanium, screen-orientation

How to change the photos' size that displayed in ScrollableView during orientation changes?

Comment: Can you be clear?  Post your .xml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the orientation change event, you need to resize the image view holding the image.

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Handling+Device+Orientation#HandlingDeviceOrientation-HandlingOrientationChanges